# Why is vim syntax highlighting on different terminals?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, vi

I am running a standard installation of OpenSuse 42.3. I ssh to the Opensuse machine via my MacOS computer. When I use vim to view files in the terminal window the syntax highlighting is pleasant to look at.  I also have a Docker image of a stock installation of OpenSuse 42.3 installed on my OpenSuse machine. If I boot up the container and open a python file with vim within the container, the syntax highlighting looks different. I did a diff on the contents of the /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim, and there were no differences between the syntax file that is being used on the OpenSuse host and the OpenSuse container.

Below on the left is what I see when I ssh from my Mac to the OpenSuse machine and open a python file. On the right is what I see when I start the docker container ( still in the same terminal window that I started for the image on the left).

[image: Python file when using vim to view the file on the host OpenSuse]
[image: Python file when using vim to view the file on the container OpenSuse]

Shouldn't the display on the terminal window of the syntax highlighted file be the same if the vim syntax files are the same?

Comment: syntax files do not define the colors just tokens, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Better_colors_for_syntax_highlighting

Comment: The issue is that on the host machine the value of the environment variable TERM=xterm-256color, whereas on the container it was only set to TERM=xterm.

Comment: This might have to do with whether vim thinks your terminal is "light" or "dark".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighting in the terminal can depend on the number of available colors. Some *colorschemes* have separate branches of color definitions depending on how many are available. You can check for yourself via

```
:set t_Co?
```

You probably get `256` for `TERM=xterm-256color` and only `16` for `TERM=xterm`.

Though you can just force `:set t_Co=256` and reload your colorscheme, it's better to fix the root cause, i.e. the wrong `TERM` value.